# Many-to-Many/Junction Table - Spring JPA Hibernate - could not set value by reflection

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

So,
I am trying to do a many to many implementation through Spring JPA.

I tried to do an embedded key implementation.
But I am getting this error

```
{
    "message": "Internal server error",
    "details": "Could not set field value [26] value by reflection : [class com.domain.configuredview.model.RelationshipViewPersonPK.personId] setter of com.domain.configuredview.model.RelationshipViewPersonPK.personId; nested exception is org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Could not set field value [26] value by reflection : [class com.domain.configuredview.model.RelationshipViewPersonPK.personId] setter of com.domain.configuredview.model.RelationshipViewPersonPK.personId"
}
```

I tried searching through all the answers but couldn't fix this.

My classes are

```
import com.domain.person.model.Person;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "relationship_view_person")
public class RelationshipViewPerson implements Serializable {

  @EmbeddedId
  private RelationshipViewPersonPK entryId;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @MapsId("viewId")
  @JoinColumn(name = "view_id", nullable = false)
  private ConfiguredView view;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @MapsId("personId")
  @JoinColumn(name = "person_id", nullable = false)
  private Person person;

  public RelationshipViewPerson(ConfiguredView view, Person person) {
    this.view = view;
    this.person = person;
    this.entryId = new RelationshipViewPersonPK(view.getId(), person.getWsGlobalId());
  }

  public void setEntryId(Long viewId, String personId) {
    this.entryId.setViewId(viewId);
    this.entryId.setPersonId(personId);
  }

  public void setView(ConfiguredView view) {
    this.view = view;
  }

  public void setPerson(Person person) {
    this.person = person;
  }

  public Person getPerson() {
    return this.person;
  }

  public ConfiguredView getView() {
    return this.view;
  }
}
```

The relationship key is

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Embeddable
@NoArgsConstructor
public class RelationshipViewPersonPK implements Serializable {

  @Column(name = "view_id")
  private Long viewId;

  @Column(name = "person_id")
  private String personId;

  public RelationshipViewPersonPK(Long viewId, String personId) {
    this.viewId = viewId;
    this.personId = personId;
  }

  // setters & getters
  public void setViewId(Long viewId) {
    this.viewId = viewId;
  }

  public void setPersonId(String personId) {
    this.personId = personId;
  }

  public String getPersonId() {
    return this.personId;
  }

  public Long getViewId() {
    return this.viewId;
  }

  // Override equals and hashCode

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
      return true;
    }

    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
      return false;
    }

    RelationshipViewPersonPK that = (RelationshipViewPersonPK) o;

    return this.viewId.equals(that.viewId) && this.personId.equals(that.personId);
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return this.viewId.hashCode() + this.personId.hashCode();
  }
}
```

The *ConfiguredView* model has PK as `id` and *Person* model has field as `wsGlobalId` . The key on the Person table is not a PK.

I have the setters, getters, constructors, and pretty much everyting in place. Not sure whats happening with Hibernate here, it cannot find the getter or something? Not sure whats happening with this.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a setter like below:

```java
public void setEntryId(RelationshipViewPersonPK entryId) {
    this.entryId.setViewId(entryId.getViewId());
    this.entryId.setPersonId(entryId.getPersonId());
}
```

instead of (or in addition to) this:

```java
public void setEntryId(Long viewId, String personId) {
    this.entryId.setViewId(viewId);
    this.entryId.setPersonId(personId);
}
```